# How to verify a windows desktop is running and online? (telemetry)

Tags: windows-10, telemetry

How can one best set up a system to poll a group on PCs running Windows 10 and generate a notification if one of them drops off of the network? I don't care if the PC crashes or the Ethernet cable is unplugged, I'm just looking for a reliable off the shelf package that will notify (via email, text, whatever) an admin that a computer is no longer available.

Thank you.

Comment: You could ping them. If they respond it means they are turned on and online, but not much more than that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)

Comment: Perhaps "online" is a misleading term, "available on the network" would be better.

Comment: This will tell you the computers that are on - `for /f "skip=3 delims=\" %A in ('net view ^| findstr /v /C:"The command completed successfully"') do Echo %A`. Or just type `net view`.